# How to get Docker metrics using docker remote API

Tags: docker

I was able to get information of my docker containers via the command:

```
echo -e "GET /containers/json HTTP/1.0\r\n" | nc -U /var/run/docker.sock
```

I also was able to found information on a specific container:

```
echo -e "GET /containers/<containerId>json HTTP/1.0\r\n" | nc -U /var/run/docker.sock
```

but I'm unable to get information about memory, cpu and I/O usage of a specific container
is it possible to get it via the remote api, or must I go directly to the file system under /sys/fs/cgroup/...?

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but you could use `GET /containers/<containerID>/top` to get the running processes. From there you should see the process ID which you can get information from in `/proc/` for example `cat /proc/processID/io` on the host.

Answer (score 0):

the API will continuously report a live stream of CPU, memory, I/O, and network metrics consumed by a specific container.

```
$ echo -ne "GET /containers/$CONTAINER_ID/stats HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n" | sudo nc -U /var/run/docker.sock
```

note : replace $CONTAINER_ID with the id of the required container
hope this helps